# Why does internet explorer push my content halfway down the page as if creating a huge margin above?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css-float, double, margin

I've created a single html page that will be used within a .aspx template. The html code I used is pretty basic and includes an email subscribe form. The form and it's code is taken directly from Mailchimp as they are the email client I'm using. The problem is that the page loads fine in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer, which pushes my whole html code down underneath the page. I have a jquery file included in the form (jquery-1.8.2.min.js) and I'm not sure if that is interfering with my html code or if it's a problem within the code itself that I havent specified correctly for Internet Explorer. I'm not sure also if it has something to do with the Mailchimp form. I've tried everything possible to fix this but nothing seems to work. If anyone could help with this or has any ideas I would really appreciate it. Please see my code and screenshots below. Thanks, Gary

Heres my code:

HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <head> <meta
 http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link
 href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> </form>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">                 
      </script>
 </head>

 <body> <div id="_wrapper">

         <div id="_formsection">


            <h1>Welcome</h1>
             <p>Subscribe for a monthly discount code</p>

         <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form-->        
         <div id="mc_embed_signup">             
         <form action="form_name_goes_here"

              method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
              name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
              class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate />            
             <div class="mc-field-group">           
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">
           <span class="asterisk"></span></label>           
input type="email" value="Enter
 your email address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" 
             id="mce-EMAIL" />          </div>          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">          <div class="response" id="mce-error-response"
 style="display:none"></div>            <div class="response"
 id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>          </div>  
            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" 
             id="mailsubmit" class="button"></div>
             </form>
                    </div>      <!--End mc_embed_signup-->

         </div><!--end form section-->

        <div id="grid_section">

            <div class="section1">
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/section1_hydrogel.jpg" 
                alt="PowerBar HydroGel Image" />
                <h4>PowerBar HydroGel Coming Soon</h4>
                <p>Click here to register for updates</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="section2">
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/section2_action_camera.jpg" 
                alt="Rollei Bullet HD Action Camera Image" />
                <h4>Rollei Bullet HD Action Camera</h4>
                <p>Get 20% off the Rollei Bullet HD and start recording your adventures</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="section3">
            <a href="">
            <img src="images/section3_gp4000.jpg" 
            alt="GP4000S Tyre Sale Image" />
            <h4>GP4000S Tyre Sale</h4>
            <p>Was €51.99 but you can get it now for €39.99 with free delivery</p></a>
            </div>

             <div class="section4">
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/section4_streetracer.jpg" 
                alt="BMC Streetracer Image" />
                <h4>BMC Streetracer for only €999.99</h4>
                <p>Great new year offer for you to buy this quality manufactured Swiss frame for only
                  €999.99</p></a>
            </div>

             <div class="section5">
                <a href="" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/section5_facebook.jpg" 
                 alt="Facebook Image" />
                <h4>Discounts on Facebook</h4>
                <p>We give out regular discounts on social media so follow us there to get the 
                 updates</p></a>
            </div>

             <div class="section6">
                <a href="">
                <img src="images/section6_isoactive.jpg" 
                 alt="Facebook Image" />
                <h4>IsoActive Sports Drink</h4>
                <p>This Isotonic Sports Drink for Maximum Hydration was €26.99 and you can get it now
                  for only €24.99</p></a>
            </div>

        </div><!--end grid section-->

    </div><!--end wrapper-->     </body>
 </html>
```

Heres my CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8"; /* CSS Document */

      body { font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Arial,Sans-serif; }

      #_wrapper{ width: 620px; 
                 overflow: hidden; 
                 margin: 0 auto; }

      /* ------------Form Section-------------- */
      #_formsection{ width: 620px;  
                     height: 350px;     
                     margin: 0 auto;    
                     background-image: url(images/background1.jpg);     
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;}

      #_formsection img{ margin: 10px 0 0 0;    
                         float: left;   
                         padding-left: 20px; }

      #_formsection h1{ margin: 30px 0 0 0;     
                        float: right;   
                        font-size: 20px;    
                        padding-right: 280px;   
                        color: #FFF;    
                        text-shadow: #666 2px 2px 1px; }

      #_formsection p{ clear: both;     
                       margin: 100px 0 10px 0;  
                       float: left;     
                       padding-left: 55px;  
                       color: #FFF;     
                       text-shadow: #666 2px 2px 1px;
                  display: inline; }

     #mc_embed_signup{ clear: both;     
                       float: left;     
                       margin-right: 0px;   
                       padding-left: 50px;  
                       width: 290px; }

     .mc-field-group{ width: 200px;     
                      float: left;  
                      overflow: hidden; }

     input#mce-EMAIL{ width: 185px;     
                      height: 25px;
                      font-size: 10px;  
                      padding-left: 10px;
                      color: #999;
                      letter-spacing: -0.02em;
                      text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
                      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e1e1e1), to(#ffffff));
                      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e1e1e1,  #ffffff);
                      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                      border-radius: 3px;
                      border: 1px solid #CCC;   
                      outline:none;
                      transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                      -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                      -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
                      border-radius:3px;
                      -webkit-border-radius:3px;
                      -moz-border-radius:3px; }

                  input#mce-EMAIL:focus {
                      box-shadow: 0 0 3px (255, 140, 0, 1);
                      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 140, 0, 1); 
                      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 140, 0, 1);
                      border:1px solid rgba(255,140,0, 0.8);  }

                 #mailsubmit { color: #999;     
                     border: 1px solid #CCC;    
                     font-size: 10px;   
                     letter-spacing: -0.02em;
                     text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
                     outline: none;
                     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e1e1e1), to(#ffffff));
                     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e1e1e1,  #ffffff);
                     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                     border-radius: 3px;    
                     width: 90px;   
                     float: right;  
                     height: 29px;  
                     cursor: pointer; }

              /* ------------End Form Section-------------- */

              /* ------------Grid Section-------------- */
                #grid_section{ clear: both;     
                               width: 620px;    
                               margin: 0 auto;  
                               margin-top: 20px; }

                   .section1 { border: 1px solid #CCC;  
                               float: left;     
                               width: 200px;
                          height: 250px;    
                               margin-right: 7px;   
                               display:inline; }

               .section1 img{  margin-top: 1px;     
                               margin-left: 1px;    
                               margin-right: 1px; }

                .section1 h4{  margin-top: 5px;     
                               margin-bottom: 0px;  
                               margin-left: 5px;    
                               color: #666;     
                               font-size: 16px;     
                               font-weight: bold; }

                 .section1 p{  margin-top: 5px;     
                               margin-left: 5px;    
                               color: #666;
                          font-size: 12px; }

                 .section1 a{ text-decoration: none;    
                              color: #666; }

                 .section1 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

                 .section2 { border: 1px solid #CCC;    
                             float: left;   
                             width: 200px;
                        height: 250px;  
                             margin-right: 7px;     
                             display:inline; }

                 .section2 img{ margin-top: 1px;    
                                margin-left: 1px;   
                                margin-right: 1px; }

                  .section2 h4{ margin-top: 5px;    
                                margin-bottom: 0px;     
                                margin-left: 5px;   
                                color: #666;    
                                font-size: 16px;    
                                font-weight: bold; }

                   .section2 p{ margin-top: 5px;    
                                margin-left: 5px;   
                                color: #666;
                           font-size: 12px; }

                   .section2 a{ text-decoration: none;  
                                color: #666; }

             .section2 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

             .section3 { border: 1px solid #CCC;    
                         float: right;  
                         width: 200px;
                            height: 250px;  
                         display:inline; }

            .section3 img{  
                        margin-top: 1px;    
                        margin-left: 1px;   
                        margin-right: 1px; }

            .section3 h4{ margin-top: 5px;
                     margin-bottom: 0px;    
                         margin-left: 5px;  
                          color: #666;   
                          font-size: 16px;  
                          font-weight: bold; }

             .section3 p{ margin-top: 5px;  
                          margin-left: 5px;     
                          color: #666;
                     font-size: 12px; }

             .section3 a{ text-decoration: none;    
                          color: #666; }

       .section3 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

              .section4 { border: 1px solid #CCC;   
                          float: left;  
                          width: 200px;
                     height: 250px;     
                          margin: 7px 7px 0 0;  
                          display:inline;   
                          overflow: hidden; }

           .section4 img{ margin-top: 1px;  
                          margin-left: 1px;     
                          margin-right: 1px; }

            .section4 h4{ margin-top: 5px;  
                          margin-bottom: 0px;   
                          margin-left: 5px;     
                          color: #666;  
                          font-size: 16px;  
                          font-weight: bold; }

             .section4 p{ margin-top: 5px;  
                          margin-left: 5px;     
                          color: #666;
                     font-size: 12px; }

             .section4 a{ text-decoration: none;    
                          color: #666; }

       .section4 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

              .section5 { border: 1px solid #CCC;   
                          float: left;  
                          width: 200px;
                     height: 250px; 
                   margin: 7px 7px 0 0;     
                          display:inline;   
                          overflow: hidden; }

          .section5 img{ margin-top: 1px;   
                         margin-left: 1px; 
                  margin-right: 1px; }

          .section5 h4{ margin-top: 5px;    
                        margin-bottom: 0px; 
                 margin-left: 5px; 
                 color: #666;   
                        font-size: 16px;    
                        font-weight: bold; }

           .section5 p{ margin-top: 5px;    
                        margin-left: 5px;   
                        color: #666;
                        font-size: 12px; }

           .section5 a{ text-decoration: none;  
                        color: #666; }

     .section5 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }

            .section6 { border: 1px solid #CCC;     
                        float: right;   
                        width: 200px;
                   height: 250px; 
                 margin: 7px 0 0 0;     
                        display:inline;     
                        overflow: hidden; }

         .section6 img{ margin-top: 1px;    
                        margin-left: 1px;   
                        margin-right: 1px; }

          .section6 h4{ margin-top: 5px; 
                 margin-bottom: 0px;    
                        margin-left: 5px; 
                 color: #666; 
                 font-size: 16px;   
                        font-weight: bold; }

           .section6 p{ margin-top: 5px;    
                        margin-left: 5px;   
                        color: #666;
                   font-size: 12px; }

           .section6 a{ text-decoration: none; 
                 color: #666; }

     .section6 a:hover{ text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: because IE thinks it's above the rules :D

Comment: You can start by pulling out code until you are only left with those containers. Only they will you know why.

Comment: If you provide jsFiddle... it will give us better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joseph. I've tried that but I think the problem has something to do with the email form I have in as it seems to activate the huge margin problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: i don't know above jsFiddle Abhijeet. What exactly will it do?

Comment: What I meant to say is so much code in question is difficult to catch. [jsFiddle.net](http://jsFiddle.net) is a site that helps to create and share these examples. So if you create the same thing on jsFiddle and then share the link, it will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Some elements are missiong from this code:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">            
  <form action="form_name_goes_here"

     method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
       name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
     class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate />           
      <div class="mc-field-group">          
     <label for="mce-EMAIL">
    <span class="asterisk"></span></label>
```

CLOSE THIS DIV ABOVE mc-field-group. ALSO FORM IS NOT CLOSED, BEST TO DOUBLE CHECK SIGN-UP FORM CODE

```
</div><!--end form section-->
```

Comment: Hi Gary, It's not only div but also part of form is missing. Cant find this tag "</form>"?

Comment: my closing form tag is here at the end:                                       <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
   <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
   </div> 
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" 
            id="mailsubmit" class="button"></div>
            </form>

Comment: Is html in your post exactly the same as the one in front of you? There's some weird stuff going on there. Now you have form tag in <head>   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <head> <meta
 http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <link
 href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> </form>

Comment: i've put the code into jsFiddle and it says that all is valid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is how you pasted into stackoverflow or not, but you need to indent your content.
The days are mainly gone where you need to save that extra overhead for the filesize.
Using notepad++ would have helped you find this error pretty quickly, what file editor do you use?

Comment: it's a ballache but indent and find all the unclosed tags. IE will be applying its own closing tags where it sees fit.

Comment: Hi everyone, got the problem fixed it was an issue with the .aspx template. I ended up having to put the form in an iframe to make it work. Thanks to you all for the help I really appreciate it!